# CSS - how to use float without any space

Tags: html, css

I have many float items with different heights inside one container.
I want that the items will fill the container without any spaces (white areas) 
but it's not working for me.

I have the code on the Fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhvgctsm/1/

```css
body {
   width : 400px;
}

.div100 {
    float: right;
    height : 60px;
    width :48%;
    background-color : red;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
.div200 {
    float: right;
    height : 100px;
    width :48%;
    background-color : blue;
        border : 1px solid black;
}

.left {
    float : left;
    width : 48%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="div100"></div>
        <div class="div200"></div>
        <div class="div200"></div>
        <div class="div100"></div>
        <div class="div200"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This type of question comes up often in SO (but hard to locate using search terms).  The most common answer to this problem is to use the jQuery plugin Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Better: https://jsfiddle.net/bhvgctsm/8/ ?

Comment: Someone closed this before it could give an answer check this one out https://jsfiddle.net/ghyfq4gg/  this works because off the very large    `padding-bottom: 999999em` and `margin-bottom: -999999em` to enforce an height on floated elements